# Plone translation issues

Tags: internationalization, plone, zope, zope.interface, plone-3.x

I am a plone Newbie and I needed to change a translated word in the .po file, the translation is in Arabic. When I changes the word to the right word and restarted the zope. My plone site is no more reading the Arabic translations from this file and displays question marks instead.

When I searched I found that I must do some synchronization with the .pot file (translation catalog) but I think this is not the actual problem. Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

You may have saved the file with the wrong encoding. Try saving the file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

I seems that you edit the file with a normal text editor. That can corrupt the files charset. To avoid this, you can use a free translation program such as poedit. Thoose programs normally take care of the charset. Use google with "translate .po YOURPLATTFORM". There are tons of free tools.
With this tools you can import .pot files also and (re)generate .po files from them. 
You just have to restart plone, when you're done, editing the file.

If you have a good editor, you can try guessing the charset and correct it manually. But this often leads to the described problem and holds the risk that you may forgot to safe with the correct charset in a later edit process.